# website login and logout

Tags: php, session, cookies, mysqli

I have my website using cookies to login and logout, it seems to work fine but I am sure there are some security issues I am not aware of. I hope for any comments or insight that could make this more secure.

Login:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['email']) && isset($_REQUEST['password'])) {
    if ($result = $usersqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='".$usersqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email'])."' AND password='".$usersqli->real_escape_string($_POST['password'])."'")) {
        if ($result->num_rows==1){
            $row = $result->fetch_object();
            $_SESSION["uid"]=$row->id;
            setcookie('email', $usersqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['email']), time()+60*60*24*365,'/');
            setcookie('password', md5($_REQUEST['password']), time()+60*60*24*365,'/');
            $usersqli->query("UPDATE users SET last_login=NOW() WHERE  email='".$usersqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email'])."' AND password='".$usersqli->real_escape_string($_POST['password'])."'"); 
            header( 'Location: index.php' ) ;
        }else{
            header( 'Location: index.php?show=login&err=Invalid login credentials' ) ;
        }
    }

}
```

Logout:

```
    setcookie('email','', time() - 60000);
    setcookie('password', '', time() - 60000);
    session_destroy();
    header("Location: index.php");
```

Header of every page:

```
if(!$_SESSION[uid] && $_REQUEST[show]!='logout'){
    if (isset($_COOKIE['email']) && isset($_COOKIE['password'])) {  
        if ($result = $usersqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='".$usersqli->real_escape_string($_COOKIE['email'])."'")) {
            if ($result->num_rows==1){
                $row = $result->fetch_object();
                if(md5($usersqli->real_escape_string($row->password))==$_COOKIE['password']){
                    $_SESSION["uid"]=$row->id;          
                }
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course, the first issue is making it work when the user does not have cookies enabled.

Comment: Or at least warn the user that they need to enable cookies to use the website

Comment: Uhm...putting the password inside your cookie doesn't sound like a great idea, for starter

Comment: i will tell users to enable cookies, i hadnt thought of that. as for putting the password in the cookie, thats how they did it in the example i read. the author claimed it was safe because it was saved as md5.  do you disagree?

Comment: Well, looking at your example, if I can borrow your computer and look at your cookies, I can log in as you.  If you're going to use cookies, only store a value associated with that session - in other words, once the user logs out, the values stored in the cookie (which should have been erased) become meaningless.

Comment: Also, it looks like you've got something about sessions in your example - if you use a php session, the cookie stuff is taken care of for you.  Of course, if you're on a shared server, you should really make sure your session is secure too, but...

Comment: Well, originally i was using only a php session, but my boss wants the website to remember the users so they dont have to log in every time they have closed their browser. I will have to read more about how to implement  a remember me to the page. I appreciate your your help

Answer (score 0):

Don't store the password in cookie - major security no-no.
There are [lots of articles](http://www.google.com/search?q=php%20login%20mysql) about how to do this.

Comment: even if its an MD5? i thought it was impossible to turn MD5 back into the original string

Comment: I think that these line here: if(!$_SESSION[uid] && $_REQUEST[show]!='logout'){
    if (isset($_COOKIE['email']) && isset($_COOKIE['password'])) will basically let me login by copying your cookie.  Even after you've logged out.  Unless there's something I'm not seeing...

Comment: Now I totally understand what you mean, and also what to do!  thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You've got problems here with session fixation in both authentication mechanisms.

I see no explicit session_start().

Why 2 separate cookies?

While the md5 hash of the password means that someone can't sniff the original password, there's nothing to stop them sniffing the hash of the password which works just as well to give them access. Running this over SSL isn't going to help - but setting the secure and http only flags on the cookies would address the latter issue.

Comment: the session is started in the page head. i used two cookies because the example I found used two cookies. i understand about the hash still being vulnerable to allow others access if they had the hash. but really, it wouldnt matter if the hash was the password or not, all they need is access to it and i see no way around it.   ill look into the http only flags.  thank you

Comment: Using a challenge mechanism for the password based authentication (e.g. use javascript to hash the password with the session cookie) combined with ant-fixation measures (when a session id is presented which does not match an unexpired session, force a new session id) would give prevent replay attacks. Forcing a new session id on authentication (by either means) would prevent fixation. Using a random value for the 'remember me' token and storing this with the user record in the database would prevent replay attacks